# Get file encoding

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect file encoding in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505562/detect-file-encoding-in-php)

How can I figure out with PHP what file encoding a file has?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Detecting the encoding is really hard for all 8 bit character sets but utf-8 (because not every 8 bit byte sequence is valid utf-8) and usually requires semantic knowledge of the text for which the encoding is to be detected.

Think of it: Any particular plain text information is just a bunch of bytes with no encoding information associated. If you look at any particular byte, it could mean *anything*, so to have a chance at detecting the encoding, you would have to look at that byte in context of other bytes and try some heuristics based on possible *language* combination.

For 8bit character sets you can never be sure though.

A demonstration of heuristics going wrong is here for example:

http://www.hoax-slayer.com/bush-hid-the-facts-notepad.html

Some 16bit sets, you have a chance at detecting because they might include a byte order mark or have every second byte set to 0.

If you just want to detect UTF-8, you can either use mb_detect_encoding as already explained, or you can use this handy little function:

```
function isUTF8($string){
    return preg_match('%(?:
    [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]        # non-overlong 2-byte
    |\xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]               # excluding overlongs
    |[\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}      # straight 3-byte
    |\xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]               # excluding surrogates
    |\xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}    # planes 1-3
    |[\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}                  # planes 4-15
    |\xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}    # plane 16
    )+%xs', $string);
}
```

Comment: Can i ask did you create that function or was it copied from elsewhere. I want to use this in some production code and i need to know the origin. Also can you elaborate on what it is doing? Thanks.

Comment: it's from a comment in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php comment from August 3rd, 2006

Answer (score 3):

mb_detect_encoding should be able to do the job.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

In it's default setup, it'll only detect ASCII, UTF-8, and a few Japanese JIS variants. It can be configured to detect more encodings, if you specify them manually. If a file is both ASCII and UTF-8, it'll return UTF-8.

Comment: I don't think your last statement is right. If it were, then ASCII would never be detected because all ASCII strings are also UTF-8. I think the mb_detect_order() function is relevant for determining what encoding is returned when more than one could be valid. By default ASCII comes before UTF-8.

Comment: According to PHP's documentation, it should work that way, yes. It just doesn't seem to. If it worked as the documentation says it should, it would never return UTF-8. When I've used it in the past, it prefers UTF-8 over ASCII, returning ASCII only when the string isn't a valid UTF-8 string.

Comment: I've had to use the function pilif posted as this one didn't always return the correct encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really, unless the file is kind enough to tell you somewhere inside it.

For example, HTML files are meant to contain a content-type meta tag near the top, so that your web browser knows what encoding is used.. eg

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

There are methods that try to guess by looking at the file and spotting byte sequences that suggest certain encodings, but these are really only guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fread() function to look at the first few bytes of the file for the "[magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Examples)", and then map that magic number against a list of known magic numbers for file types.

Comment: Only up to a rather limited point.  The encoding for a UTF-16 file is indicated by a BOM (byte-order mark), to distinguish between little-endian and big-endian (UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE).  But for other code sets, there is no mandatory identification - they just get on with presenting the data in their encoding.

Answer (score 0):

BlackAura's suggestion is very good, IMHO.

Another option is to call [file](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/file-1.html#scrolltoc)(1) on the file in question using system() or the like. Often, it is able to tell you the encoding as well. It should be available in any sane UNIX environment.