# How to use Regional Language in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html

I am running following code to select and change text language. But When I am selecting my regional language then Its showing something like this. You can see the example here

[Example Link](http://www.hlinker.com/php6/)

```
à¤†à¤ªà¤•à¥‡ à¤‡à¤¨à¤¬à¥‰à¤•à¥à¤¸ à¤®à¥‡à¤‚ 36 à¤¸à¤‚à¤¦à¥‡à¤¶ à¤¹à¥ˆ.à¤œà¤¿à¤¸à¤®à¥‡ à¤†à¤ªà¤¨à¥‡ 4 à¤¨à¤¹à¥€à¤‚ à¤ªà¥à¥‡ à¤¹à¥ˆ
```

My Code is ..

```
<?php
$lang=$_POST['lang'];
if($lang=='hindi')
{
printf(file_get_contents("hindi.txt"),36,4);
}
if($lang=='english')
{
printf(file_get_contents("template.txt"),36,4);
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<select name="lang">
<option value="hindi">Hindi</option>
<option value="english">English</option>
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your question? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You need `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`.

Comment: What is the encoding of `hindi.txt`?

Comment: It should show text written in my regional language i.e. Hindi. And I have copied my regional langauge text in hindi.txt file. But instead of showing my regional langauge its showing some meaningless symbols.

Comment: Then check if your PHP file has what Antony mentioned in a comment and see in which format the file was saved as, UTF-8 or ANSI, or other. It could be a number of things.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is useful when encoding the actual file doesn't help: [How to set UTF-8 encoding for a PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056646/how-to-set-utf-8-encoding-for-a-php-file)

The answer above sends a manual over-riding header to the browser to tell it that it should be displaying as UTF-8.

Basically just make sure you're saving all of your .php files as UTF-8 encoded, the same goes for making sure all database tables and forms are encoded in UTF-8 - otherwise you'll still get odd characters appearing.

Editors like Notepad++ (On Windows) have a setting to make all new documents UTF-8 by default - might be worth taking a look at your editor and seeing if there is also an option - saves hassle in future (if you forget - been there and done that).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

tag in your html head section.
Ii you are using only raw php to generate the output then use this meta tag like that -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<html>
<head><title>Your Page Title here</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
   $lang=$_POST['lang'];
   if($lang=='hindi')
   {
   printf(file_get_contents("hindi.txt"),36,4);
   }
   if($lang=='english')
   {
   printf(file_get_contents("template.txt"),36,4);
   }
   ?>
   <form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
   <select name="lang">
   <option value="hindi">Hindi</option>
   <option value="english">English</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```