# How to echo a £ sign (UK) as output? PHP

Tags: php, html

```
 echo "<br/>that will be" . " " . $pricetotal;
```

I need to add a uk "£"  before the $pricetotal such that I see the following in the browser:

> That will be £ 2.99

Comment: you can't just do `echo "<br/>that will be £" . $pricetotal;` ?

Comment: oops that was a bit silly of me!!! thank you very much.

Comment: Please at least go through php script language.I hope you will get solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like that:

```
echo "<br/>that will be" . " £" . $pricetotal;
```

you can also use html entity:

```
echo "<br/>that will be &pound;" . $pricetotal;
```

or

```
echo "<br/>that will be &#163;" . $pricetotal;
```

Comment: True, in the first and third cases *if* you have set the encoding to be consistent with your source code. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5056646/67392

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
echo "<br/>that will be" . " £" . $pricetotal;
```

or

```
echo "<br/>that will be" . " &pound;" . $pricetotal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either try like

```
echo "&pound;";
```

Or even by character code you can try like

```
echo chr(163);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTMLEntity

```
echo "<br/>that will be &pound;" . $pricetotal;
```

Also make sure that your website is encoded with a multibyte charset which supports the `£` char.
I suggest using UTF-8.
Include

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in your `<head>` tag of your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
echo "<br/>that will be" . " £" . $pricetotal;
```

and

```
echo "<br/>that will be &pound;" . $pricetotal;
```

work but under the following strict conditions:

- meta charset should be set as utf-8 inside html head

> ```
> <meta charset="utf-8" />
> ```

- The php source code itself is encoded as utf-8 characters
- The character encoding of browser should be utf-8. Normally, when setting meta charset as described above, the browser detects automatically that the html page is uncoded with utf-8

What is really important is that whole html rendering chain should be utf-8 to allow you to control your character encoding and to avoid strange behaviors. It is also the case when using for instance mysql database. The database encoding should be in advance and planned to be utf-8. Otherwise, it becomes very complex to rectify the encoding problem.