# PHP: Change charset encoding for Hindi

Tags: php, unicode

```
<?php 
$unicodeChar = '\u0939';
echo json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"');
?>
```

prints :  à¤¹

expected : ह

unicode '\u0939' decoding to original character using json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set UTF-8 encoding for a PHP file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056646/how-to-set-utf-8-encoding-for-a-php-file)

Answer (score 1):

Set character encoding to `UTF-8` for displaying `Hindi` characters.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/779946)

Here we are initiating a header which will set charset for displaying the content in hindi charset.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
$unicodeChar = '\u0939';
echo json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"');
```

**Solution 2:**

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/779955)

Here we are setting default charset to `UTF-8` using `ini_set`.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');

$unicodeChar = '\u0939';
echo json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"');
```

Comment: Hey thanks @Sahil Gulati upvoted for you because i gained a new thing

Comment: @SahilGulati what  exactly happens without setting default charset to `UTF-8` ?

Comment: there must be some other encoding which you are using in your PHP. So i have changed it to `UTF-8`.