# Wordpress - Random squares ▢ appearing on website in Windows Chrome

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am having random squares like ▢ appearing on the website, these keep randomly appearing in different parts of the website from time to time.

I've tested on Mac/Windows and multiple browsers and this is only appearing in Windows Chrome.

They are appearing in the content that you can amend in the CMS but I can only get rid them through the CMS on a Windows computer through Chrome as they don't show anywhere else.

Why is this happening?

I've tried updating the wp-config.php and changing:-

`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');` to `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`

And even commenting out both of these lines:-

`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');`

but neither of these fixed the issue, any suggestions?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056646/how-to-set-utf-8-encoding-for-a-php-file)

Comment: @BhavikShah This did not fix the issue, also this is also set in the php.ini `default_charset = "utf-8"`