# How to convert characters in PHP?

Tags: php, character

I am having these weird characters -

```
ÔÇ£ should be "
ÔÇØ should be "
ÔÇÖ should be '
```

Any way to convert them into the correct UTF8 format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set UTF-8 encoding for a PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056646/how-to-set-utf-8-encoding-for-a-php-file)

Comment: Not really. The problem is my original data is like that somehow. Therefore, I don't know how to convert them back.