# How to add Serbian Latin and Serbian Cyrillic in SQL Table with $_POST method

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have problem with inserting values from my PHP website into SQL Table when user insert Serbian Latin or Serbian Cyrillic letters. I use utf8_unicode_ci format for my tables. I can manually  add Serbian Latin or Serbian Cyrillic, but when I do it through PHP page it does not enter Serbian Latin or Serbian Cyrillic letters into table. How to enable Serbian Latin stores in variable in php $_POST method? Any other solutions?

Comment: What is you page & server charset?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056646/how-to-set-utf-8-encoding-for-a-php-file

Comment: I really don't know, how can I check it? I use AWS server Ubuntu18.04

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql