# Unable to read hyphenated values in csv

Tags: php, csv

While reading hyphenated values from a csv file, I see the hyphen is gets converted into `â€`

My csv file contains data such as :

```
05‐30‐2012,user,500 
06‐30‐2012,user,1500
```

After reading the lines I get :

```
05â€30â€2012,user,500 
06â€30â€2012,user,1500
```

Why is it happening? How do I correct it ?

This is what I have done  :

```
$lines = file('data.csv');  

foreach($lines as $line_num => $line){
  if($line != ''){

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($line);       
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what encoding is the source file in?

Comment: It's a weird Unicode hyphen `U+2010`. You are printing it out in a Latin-1 page.

Comment: It's not "encoding" it as that, it's "interpreting" the encoded value. That's probably an `emdash` (of some sort).

Comment: @JaredFarrish How is his code interpreting anything?

Comment: The csv file uses UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @Jack - I mean it's being read with the wrong encoding by what's displaying the underlying code.

Comment: str_replace would work if you cant get encoding sorted

Comment: Have you tried [`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279282/set-http-header-to-utf-8-php) before output?

Answer (score 0):

If your output encoding is not UTF-8, then you need to convert your UTF-8 input file to your output encoding. For example, assuming your output to the browser should be `ISO-8859-1` (a common default with Apache setups), then `utf8_decode` will convert your UTF-8 CSV data into the proper encoding.

```
$lines = file('data.csv');  

foreach($lines as $line_num => $line){
  if($line != ''){

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r(utf8_decode($line));
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

If you want UTF-8 output (or if you are fine with that), set the [`default_charset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) PHP setting as early in your script as possible so PHP will set the correct HTTP header.

```
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
```