# Space turns into capital 'i' on Arabic website

Tags: php, html, css

I am building an Arabic website using PHP. It is probably an encoding error, but spaces in the Arabic language turns into capital "i"'s for some reason. I have included [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) enconding in the website's main CSS, but the error still exists.

Note: This only happens when using Chrome on Windows OS.

Comment: not enough info to help, make sure you follow things on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279282/set-http-header-to-utf-8-php

Comment: Is the HTML file encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Answer (score 1):

After thorough research, it appeared that it wasn't a Charset issue. I changed the fonts around in some CSS tags and the "i" appeared in some fonts and disappeared in others. So, I chose one that worked. Thanks for everyone's help.