# How to convert latin1_swedish_ci to utf8-general-ci

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3, collation

I have a field with `latin1_swedish_ci` collation and inserted data is visible to me as a set of question marks `????????`.

[image]

How to convert existing (??)question mark data with original data?

Note:(???)question mark data in table in actually in gujarati language data.

I am using code-igniter,mysql and phpmyadmin

Comment: Hi Maulik. Please include sample of your table structure & data and also the query you have tried into your question. Thanks

Comment: I am edit my question and attached my one data

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15605490/7356355

Comment: See Question Marks in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored - it lists the likely configuration problems that cause that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the column's character set 
sample code is below.

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `name` `name` VARCHAR(45) 
CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

**Note:**
When records are already ??????? in the table, the data to be reinserted again.

The existing data will not change once collation changes.

Comment: i will try your query but it will affect 0 row. collation is chnages latiion1_swident to utf8 but inserted data (???? question mark) not replace with (typed by client) data. please help me

Comment: this was typed by user in other language and i boss client want to know exact data

Comment: Then there is no option to get back the data back. Should have tested this for other languages or need to accept the fault and move on.

Comment: If you need confirmation then try asking a new question then the community will share their knowledge.

Comment: Beware - There are different ways to use `ALTER`.  Using the wrong technique only makes things worse.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

The default encoding for inbound connections isn't set properly. DEFAULT CHARSET will return as utf8 however character_set_server will be something different. In the above, the character_set_server was set as latin1.

**Resolution**

Set default-character-set=utf8, as detailed in
[Configuring Database Character Encoding.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-database-character-encoding-177698.html)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you can change the collation through the phpmyadmin page

Follow this steps

> 1) Select you database
>
> 2) Go to Operations in the menu
>
> 3) Scroll Down to the bottom and you will see the collation

Change the collation and click GO

[image]