# Whats the difference between MySQL and MySQLi concerning Character-Encoding?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character-encoding, mysqli

I was using `mysqli` in php code to connect to database, i like its OOP features.
Database contains data in `Persian` language and collation is set to `utf8_persian_ci`.

after creating a connection, the `charset` is set to `utf8`:

```
<?php


class DBHandler {

    private $DB_HOST = "localhost"; //localhost
    private $DB_USER = "------"; //root
    private $DB_PASS = "------"; // ""
    private $DB_NAME = "------"; //test
    private $mysqli;
    private $username;

    public function __construct($user) {
        $this->username = $user;
        // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->DB_HOST, $this->DB_USER, $this->DB_PASS, $this->DB_NAME);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to connect to the database. Error number: " . $this->mysqli->connect_errno);
        }
        $this->mysqli->set_charset("uft8");
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        //We are done with the database. Close the connection handle.
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }
}
```

i was expecting to retrieve data in proper encoding, but after query-ing the database, all characters turned to `?`.

I simply replaced all `mysqli` instances with `mysql` function and everything worked fine.

I'm wondering what was causing that and what can i do to use `mysqli` functions and get data   in right encoding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: the mysql extension is deprecated. You're better off sticking to mysqli, or switching to PDO.

What you're saying about the question marks (diamonds?), isn't necessarily a DB issue. Might be your script is using a wrong encoding. Lots of people having the diamond thing, [and it can be solved with a single line of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279294/2580119).

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Sorry, i should have been more specific, all my php files are saved under `utf-8` encoding, i used `header(...)` function already, it didnt help until i JUST replaced all `mysqli` function with `mysql` equivalent function and nothing more, thats why i'm all confused

Comment: Hmm... now I see something. you used **uft8**. Shouldn't it be **utf8** ?Or is it just a typo in the question?

Comment: Ohh, i wish it was typo in question but i actually did that stupid mistake, I wasted a lot of time to figure out the problem and didn't look carefully where i should have, thanks for your answer and sorry for wasting your time over my stupid mistake, i am accepting your answer

Comment: Haha don't worry. I can't sleep anyway, so not a lot of time-wasting going on at my side ;) The most important part is: you found it! :D