# PHP's var_dump / print_r output is garbled - encoding issue?

Tags: php, debugging, character-encoding, gzip

I'm having a problem where on a server the output of `var_dump` and `print_r` come out entirely garbled. `print_r` outputs pure gibberish (eg. `��]{W�8�����-` ... etc), while `var_dump` at least gives `string (1664)`, followed by similar gibberish (though this time wrapped in double quotes).

This looks like a character encoding issue, but no encoding I can find seems to fix it (and I don't know why just dumping a PHP object should be outputting non-ascii characters anyway), and `echo` works fine. Alternatively, I wonder if it could be a gzip issue. Either way, I suspect it must be something in PHP or Apache's configuration, but I have no idea how to fix it.

I'd be very grateful if anyone has any suggestions as to how fix this!

---

**Update:** on further investigation, it seems it's a problem specific to the particular object I'm trying to dump. The object in question is decoded JSON requested (via curl) from an API. Is it possible that either `json_decode` or `curl` could be misconfigured / mangling the encoding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279282/set-http-header-to-utf-8-using-php

Comment: No, as far as I can see, it's a different issue. This is not a general encoding problem. It's specifically a problem with the output of `print_r` and `var_dump`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to print ?

Comment: I'm trying to dump a PHP object representing an API response. Interestingly, I can dump strings and arrays ok, it seems, but this particular object gets totally garbled.

Comment: This definitely isn't answered by the "possible duplicate" question - as stated in the question, (1) I've tried different encodings, and (2) if it were a general HTML / HTTP encoding problem, it doesn't seem likely that it would only affect the output of `var_dump` / `print_r`

Comment: You trying to parse a json ? You maybe show some code explaining what you are trying to do, because there are different types of encoding issues.

Comment: Try to use `$contents = utf8_encode($contents);` than `$results = json_decode($contents); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I finally got to the bottom of this problem (I think!)

The problem seems to be that the API's output was being run through `json_decode` whether it was JSON or not. MySQL errors were causing an error page, not a JSON response, which when run through `json_decode` (by the API-handling code that received it) before `var_dump` produced garbled character salad, as above.