# html5 meta charset-utf-8 not working

Tags: jquery, html, meta

i am using this meta.

```
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

i have used this text:

```
<p>Vignerons de père en fils depuis 1847 notre Maison se situe au cœur du vignoble champenois, à quelques kilomètres d’Epernay sur la commune de Moussy.</p>
```

show my text :

Vignerons de p�re en fils depuis 1847 notre Maison se situe au c�ur du vignoble champenois, � quelques kilom�tres d�Epernay sur la commune de Moussy.

> not working charset="UTF-8".

Comment: Do you set your text editor encoding at UTF-8 ?

Comment: What should you expect to see? 
Is that the text above you have in your document?

Comment: @MatthieuLemoine  can you tell me? what is txt editor encoding UTF8?

Comment: @Angu What text editor did you use to create this html file ? If the file encoding is not set to UTF-8 you will have encoding error

Comment: @Angu Save your file in UTF8 or use relevant HTML entities code: `Vignerons de p&egrave;re` etc... http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: @A.Wolff . no this is dynamic data text

Comment: @Angu How dynamic? User input? Data from server?

Comment: @A.Wolff. data from server

Comment: @Angu So encode server script in UTF8. If data comes from database, you have to set relevant encoding too. What IDE/text editor are you using?

Comment: @A.Wolff. i am using sublime

Comment: So: http://superuser.com/questions/581553/sublime-text-2-encoding-utf-8

Comment: If you are using PHP, check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279282/set-http-header-to-utf-8-using-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens. It happened to me as well. what you should do is:1) open your file in notepad(.aspx or php or or html or whatever.) And save it, and specify UTF-8 from save-file-dialog-box. Problem will be solved

Answer (score 2):

The correct encoding needs to be ensured across all stages of development and deployment including:

1. text editor or IDE (check what the default encoding is)
2. source control (check the right encoding is stored)
3. server (check the checkout has the right encoding on filesystem)
4. web server (check the web server is serving using the right encoding)