# 406 response with a $.post request jQuery to external PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess, http-status-code-406

I'm trying to post large amounts of text via `$.post` in jQuery and getting a 406 response. It works fine under around 300 characters. Below is my code:

**index.php**

*html*

```
<form class="formss" action="index.php">
    <textarea id="submittts" name="tts" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
</form>
```

*jQuery*

```
$('.save').click(function() {
    $.post('store.php', $('.formss').serialize())
});
```

**store.php**

```
<?php
$tts = $_POST['tts'];
$texttostore = $tts;

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "notes";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO notes (code)
VALUES ('$texttostore')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo stripslashes(str_replace('\r\n',PHP_EOL,$texttostore));
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterCheckURLEncoding Off
</IfModule>
```

Getting the following response:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUZpX.png

Have also tried with a local form submit, but it would also bring up a bad request.

**Note:** All whitespace and formatting is preserved when stored, and that is intentional

If anyone could help me out that would be great, thanks :)

Comment: Thats why I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting the error. Same comes up with an ajax request

Comment: 406 response means that `content-type` in your response is not acceptable to the browser. See the `Accept` request header for your Ajax call and see if the `content-type` response header matches with one of the values in your request

Comment: @arkantos I see that the content length being sent is more than 'accepted' I guess? Here is a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/SSczVGa.png

Comment: @vinayakj, tried that again, didnt work.

Comment: @vinayakj.. 406 is more about some invalid response type that is not acceptable which is making the request. I think using $.ajax directly will not make any difference as $.post internally uses $.ajax

Comment: content-length is not an issue here, it's just the size of your request and response. Actual issue here is `charset`. As you see in your screenshot, request headers `charset=UTF-8` but response headers `charset=iso-8859-1` which is not understood by the browser. Hence the error while parsing the response.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I've tried set `contentType: "charset=iso-8859-1;"` in an Ajax request, but nothing actually gets stored through php

Comment: just setting by content-type header in your Ajax request will not help, It's the browser which is making the actual request, so your browser should be able to understand and interpret the response. You need to change your `charset` in response headers. Look at my answer for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browsers make a request for information from the server. When this happens, it sends an `Accept` header. This tells the server in what formats the browser can accept the data. If the server cannot send data in a format requested in the `Accept` header, the server sends the `406 Not Acceptable error`.

From the screenshot attached in the comments, you can see clearly that `charset` in response headers is `iso-8859-1`. Just send the response in `UTF-8` encoding and that should solve the issue.

Have a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279282/set-http-header-to-utf-8-using-php#4279294) link for setting charset header in PHP response.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I've tried setting `header('Content-Type: charset=utf-8');` to both index.php & store.php however I'm still getting a 406 :/ Response header still comes up as `Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: did you verify the same in your response headers ? like you did earlier in dev tools

Comment: Yeah, however when I send small blocks of text, the response header is actually: `Content-Type:charset=utf-8`

Comment: Hmm I won't be of much help unless I have a closer look at your code. Unfortunately you don't even have enough rep to discuss this over chat

Comment: Since its a small project, I uploaded it to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/5R0wKteU http://pastebin.com/4Ncq8P1g and the site is http://notes.hkbot.io/ If you'd like to have a look, that'd be awesome, thanks :)

Comment: Steps to replicate the issue in your site ?

Comment: Adding a small block of text such as "ok here is a block of text" will go through, but a larger block, such as the code in pastebin will bring up the error, then clicking options (top right) then save

Comment: In your site, I can still see the charset as `iso-8859-1` not `UTF-8`. You have this line `header('Content-Type: charset=utf-8');` in your PHP file while it should be `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`, You forgot the actual text/html content type value, charset is additional info about the response encoding.. see if that helps

Comment: Still bringing up the error when saving a block of code, but when it is a long block of plain text, it doesnt get saved by sql but doesnt bring up an error

Comment: Did you make those changes in your site ? I still see `iso-8859-1` instead of `utf-8` at http://notes.hkbot.io :)

Comment: Yeah lol, added `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` to both store.php and index.php

Comment: Wooow mate. I found the problem. Textarea cant process <script> tags.. so its bringing up a 406 error. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Cool.. You found the issue on your own :-)