# HTML Charset error with Javascript, Ajax Content from another php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have this HTML document with javascript that delivers AJAX funtionality:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script
...
getRequest(
      'myAjax.php?url='
...
</body>
</html>
```

In this HTML file all "üöä..." are shown correct. But in this code I make a AJAX to the myAjax.php?url='...' file. It returns the content I want. Including text. But this Text appears then with charset errors like: gef�hrdet or w�nschen

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you don't transmit the content from `myAjax.php` encoded as UTF-8 but ISO-8859-1 or something. You need to set the UTF-8 content encoding in your PHP.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279294/2535335) or [that](https://allseeing-i.com/How-to-setup-your-PHP-site-to-use-UTF8) helps.

Comment: I already tried to do that but it did not work. Can you maybe show me an example?

Comment: Yes it worked. I simply changed echo('...'); to echo(utf8_encode ('...')); Thank you very much!

Comment: Just added another source that explains it. Can you open the URL in a browser and look at the content-encoding in the developer tools? (see: http://imgur.com/TmQ8MDD)