# MySQL UTF8 Characters load

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

OMG I AM SOO SORRY I HAVE WRONG CODE TYPE :D HERE IS AN EDIT

OK I somehow figured out how to import UTF8 characters in MYSQL but when I load them they are not UTF8. And YES I have

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```

Look At this http://prntscr.com/b13xel . First post is OK but its not UTF8 it is from normal chars latin i think. But 2ND post isnt working :/ I have stored with UTF8 Charset in mysql http://prntscr.com/b13y2n (2ND is Test and Test2 if you dont get it xD) . I think I spelled it wrong xD but NVM I think you will understand me.

This is the code:

```
<div class = "tablatekst">
                <?php
                $novostid = 1;
                while($novostid < 500)
                {
                    $sqlnovosti = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM novosti WHERE ID = $novostid"); 
                    if(mysql_num_rows($sqlnovosti) > 0)
                    {
                        while($red = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlnovosti))
                        {
                            $nnaslov = $red['Naslov'];
                            $ntekst = $red['Tekst']; 
                        }
                        echo "<h2> $nnaslov </h2>";
                        echo $ntekst;
                        echo "<br><hr><br>";
                    }
                    $novostid = $novostid + 1;
                }
                ?>


            </div>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @tadman please do not put down sql in my opinion its far easier to use then sqli i mean literally went from $row = mysql_fecth_object to $row = mysqli::fetch_results its confusing and unfamiliar to a lot of people and sql is still used way more then new methods

Comment: @JoséphFlames Don't even start. `mysql_query` is **gone** in PHP 7. This argument is over, the PHP core team decided it was best to get rid of it permanently. Please, stop advocating for something that's dead. It's also full of bugs that will never, ever get fixed. By any measure PDO is easier to do correctly and consistently because it has very good support for **prepared statements** and these are a must-have in any database layer.

Comment: LOL NVM :P :/ xD :3 WTF?  I thought this forum was about encoding of natural languages in computers, not about cryptic thumb chatter.

Comment: @tadman going to PHP 7 without sql is like going from IOS 8.1.3 to IOS 9

Comment: You have a problem, take it up with the PHP core team and not me. They rarely remove things, backwards compatibility is a concern for them, but as that interface is the source of so many problems even they decided it's better off dead. PHP still has tons of SQL support, MySQL included,  just not the `mysql_query` function or its associated other methods. Use PDO or an ORM. Stop trying to promote this terrible, ancient interface. There really is *nothing* to love about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this before your while:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

However, I strongly recommend you to migrate to mysqli

Comment: OK Thanks :D I am only familiar with this version of mysql but I will try to learn something from newest

Comment: @IlePopivanov, it's not about mysql version. actually, php deprecated mysql library and recommends to use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: LOL :P Then  I will not. xD I will learn it in school or maybe some day :3 But no today

Answer (score 0):

What are the content-type headers set to in your PHP script?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279294/6275228

> Use [`header`](http://php.net/header) to modify the HTTP header:
>
> ```
> header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
> ```
>
> Note to call this function before any output has been sent to the
>   client. Otherwise the header has been sent too and you obviously can’t
>   change it any more. You can check that with
>   [`headers_sent`](http://php.net/headers_sent). See the [manual page of
>   `header`](http://php.net/header) for more information.

Comment: I have charset but I coped style line xD I did edited and I fixed it thanks to Mojtaba

Comment: @IlePopivanov, good to hear you fixed. Please select the correct answer. So, no more developer spends time to open this post.

Comment: @IlePopivanov it's important to set the right charset at both client and server side. Keep that in mind next time.