# UTF-8 encoding not working when running on other server

Tags: javascript, php, html

A friend of mine has asked me to add some media queries to the website in the link below. The problem is when he tried to run it on his host, cyrilic symbols stopped displaying properly. Instead this kind of text is shown: вЂў Р’РёРґРµРѕ вЂ. I have added charset meta-tag to index.html file with Russian text and that still did not solve the problem. Someone, please, help me out! I suspect the solution lies somewhere in back end but I am not really an expert in that.

Here is the link to the website:
https://deekourtsman.com/new/

Comment: Sure its not you.  `Ok guys, this friend of mine want to know...`  I mean its ok if it's your server no one will beat you up for it.  Seriously there is a dozen different things I can think of, and your question doesn't narrow it down.  IS it content from a database, what's the collation for the field etc. etc.  P.S I hate character encoding.

Comment: That server responds with `Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251`

Comment: Thanks! How could I change it? Is there a way to make the files be interpreted as UTF-8 despite local server settings?

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably comes from the web server configuration, but using the `header()` function in php may resolve the issue:

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279282/set-http-header-to-utf-8-using-php).

Answer (score 0):

Include it in your header section

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

or you can also calling `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` in your PHP script