# Symbols instead of text, how to change?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I make pages with Russian texts and in chrome veiw-code see this:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lkyn.png)

How can I change this symbols to text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cyrillic text should automatically be converted if properly formatted.
Look at this page for reference on Cyrillic signs as HTML entities;
[W3 Schools Cyrillic text](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_cyrillic.asp)

You might also want to specify that your website is using UTF-8 by placing the meta-charset tag in the header section of your HTML;

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Comment: Correct. I have that in my proposed answer.

Comment: The screenshot you attached shows code, not the rendered view. Are you not getting the cyrillic text in your view?

Comment: at page i see cyrillic text, but in source code via browser - these symbols

Comment: Try to change the font in Chrome to one that you know supports Cyrillic. Have you tried the same debug in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont have way to comment I have to put, cannot you tell the page to use russian alphabet?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't put your code i assume that you didn't set the charset to utf-8.

Try [Set HTTP header to UTF-8 using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279282/set-http-header-to-utf-8-using-php)