# Problem with mutated vowel (umlauts) within a html/php contact-form

Tags: php, html, utf-8, contact-form

German mutated vowels (ö,ä,ü, etc) are not displayed correctly in the emails, sent over a html/php contact-form even the the UTF-8 declaration is set.

PHP file:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: Website'; 
    $to = 'xxx@gmx.de'; 
    $subject = 'Hi there';
    $human = $_POST['human'];

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '')
```

In the html file the utf declaration is set as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

The special characters looks like this "Ã¼"

Answer (score -1):

For `php` you need to use the `header` function to make sure that the `HTTP` header is set to `UTF-8`.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279282/set-http-header-to-utf-8-using-php) link.

In a nutshell:

```php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Call this before any data is sent (right after your `require` and `import` statements).