# Strange characters in require_once() paths in stack trace

Tags: php

I just downloaded one of my wordpress site from live, to setup locally.
now when I go to the home page I see strange characters,

```
Warning: require_once(framework/framework.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in òœ/www/humar/wp-content/plugins/custom-coming-soon-page/index.php on line 20

Call Stack:
    0.0000     314816   1. {main}() /var/www/humar/wp-admin/index.php:0
    0.0002     324296   2. require_once('çßœ/www/humar/wp-admin/admin.php') /var/www/humar/wp-admin/index.php:10
    0.0003     324584   3. require_once('ƒ„œ/www/humar/wp-load.php') cØœÀçi:30
    0.0005     325156   4. require_once('W‡œ/www/humar/wp-config.php') :30
    0.0006     326684   5. require_once('œ/www/humar/wp-settings.php') W‡œ/www/humar/wp-config.php:90
    0.0304    2295464   6. include_once('òœ/www/humar/wp-content/plugins/custom-coming-soon-page/index.php') 
EÝ:190


Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'framework/framework.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/ZF/library:/usr/share/ZF/extras/library') in òœ/www/humar/wp-content/plugins/custom-coming-soon-page/index.php on line 20

Call Stack:
    0.0000     314816   1. {main}() /var/www/humar/wp-admin/index.php:0
    0.0002     324296   2. require_once('çßœ/www/humar/wp-admin/admin.php') /var/www/humar/wp-admin/index.php:10
    0.0003     324584   3. require_once('ƒ„œ/www/humar/wp-load.php') cØœÀçi:30
    0.0005     325156   4. require_once('W‡œ/www/humar/wp-config.php') :30
    0.0006     326684   5. require_once('œ/www/humar/wp-settings.php') W‡œ/www/humar/wp-config.php:90
    0.0304    2295464   6. include_once('òœ/www/humar/wp-content/plugins/custom-coming-soon-page/index.php') 
EÝ:190
```

---

var dump of my $_Server and $_ENV from local and server machine:

***Server***

```
array(26) {
  ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
  string(26) "/home/mysite1/public_html"
  ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=>
  string(7) "CGI/1.1"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=>
  string(63) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=>
  string(13) "gzip, deflate"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=>
  string(14) "en-us,en;q=0.5"
  ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=>
  string(10) "keep-alive"
  ["HTTP_COOKIE"]=>
  string(245) ""
  ["HTTP_HOST"]=>
  string(15) "mysite.com"
  ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
  string(74) "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"
  ["PATH"]=>
  string(13) "/bin:/usr/bin"
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=>
  string(3) "200"
  ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=>
  string(14) "120.211.169.138"
  ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
  string(5) "43397"
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
  string(3) "GET"
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(8) "/env.php"
  ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
  string(34) "/home/mysite1/public_html/env.php"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(8) "/env.php"
  ["SERVER_ADDR"]=>
  string(13) ""
  ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=>
  string(25) "webmaster@mysite.com"
  ["SERVER_NAME"]=>
  string(15) "mysite.com"
  ["SERVER_PORT"]=>
  string(2) "80"
  ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
  string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
  ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
  string(6) "Apache"
  ["UNIQUE_ID"]=>
  string(24) "T14tb63sWlIAADSScZQAAAAO"
}
```

**$_SERVER**

```
array(30) {
  ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
  string(26) "/home/mysite1/public_html"
  ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=>
  string(7) "CGI/1.1"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=>
  string(63) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=>
  string(13) "gzip, deflate"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=>
  string(14) "en-us,en;q=0.5"
  ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=>
  string(10) "keep-alive"
  ["HTTP_COOKIE"]=>
  string(245) ""
  ["HTTP_HOST"]=>
  string(15) "mysite.com"
  ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
  string(74) "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"
  ["PATH"]=>
  string(13) "/bin:/usr/bin"
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=>
  string(3) "200"
  ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=>
  string(14) "120.211.169.138"
  ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
  string(5) "43397"
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
  string(3) "GET"
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(8) "/env.php"
  ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
  string(34) "/home/mysite1/public_html/env.php"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(8) "/env.php"
  ["SERVER_ADDR"]=>
  string(13) ""
  ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=>
  string(25) "webmaster@mysite.com"
  ["SERVER_NAME"]=>
  string(15) "mysite.com"
  ["SERVER_PORT"]=>
  string(2) "80"
  ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
  string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
  ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
  string(6) "Apache"
  ["UNIQUE_ID"]=>
  string(24) "T14tb63sWlIAADSScZQAAAAO"
  ["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(8) "/env.php"
  ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
  int(1331572079)
  ["argv"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["argc"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

---

**Local**

**$_ENV**

```
array(0) {
}
```

**$_SERVER**

```
array(26) {
  ["HTTP_HOST"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
  string(74) "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=>
  string(63) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=>
  string(14) "en-us,en;q=0.5"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=>
  string(13) "gzip, deflate"
  ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=>
  string(10) "keep-alive"
  ["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]=>
  string(9) "max-age=0"
  ["PATH"]=>
  string(28) "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
  ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=>
  string(70) "
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

"
  ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
  string(22) "Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)"
  ["SERVER_NAME"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["SERVER_ADDR"]=>
  string(9) "127.0.0.1"
  ["SERVER_PORT"]=>
  string(2) "80"
  ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=>
  string(9) "127.0.0.1"
  ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
  string(8) "/var/www"
  ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=>
  string(19) "webmaster@localhost"
  ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
  string(28) "/var/www/mysite/env.php"
  ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
  string(5) "58712"
  ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=>
  string(7) "CGI/1.1"
  ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
  string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
  string(3) "GET"
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(16) "/mysite/env"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(20) "/mysite/env.php"
  ["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(20) "/mysite/env.php"
  ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
  int(1331572869)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at:

- `/var/www/humar/wp-admin/index.php`
- `/var/www/humar/wp-admin/wp-config.php`
- `/var/www/humar/wp-content/plugins/custom-coming-soon-page/index.php`

to see if you find any of the unexpected characters there.

`framework/framework.php` isn't a file from Wordpress' standard distribution, so I assume it may have to do with the custom-coming-soon-page plugin you got there.

Comment: yes, I've custom coming soon plugin. but, I do not see single quote (') as strange character. I find nothing suspicious there like my **.../coming--/index.php** `require_once("framework/framework.php");
require_once('framework/init.php');` there is nothing strange, + it is the same code working online

Comment: first of all: does the file exist where the require_once is looking for? the path of the file which is failing to include is being printed correctly... there might be some strange behaviour on the representation of the error that is throwing you off... maybe encoding has nothing to do with the Fatal error here

Comment: yes it does, I mean all the files are where they are required, but the strange char appended to the string is changing the actual path...

Comment: I'd suggest then printing some system variables to see the differences in the environment between your local server and your live server. $_SERVER, $_ENV, etc.

Comment: I've added my local and server. another difference on my local and server machine is, I've PHP Version 5.2.14 on server, but, PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9 on local machine. could it be a problem?

Comment: I was looking at [this utf8 problem] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505562/detect-file-encoding-in-php), and I think it could be the same issue with me as well... can any one confirm ? and if so, how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: That's an error with file reading, you're getting the error in PHP's error display. You could check the encoding of your PHP files to see if there's anything strange there. I see you're working on Linux, you can use the `file` command: `file -i your_file.php`. That will print something like this: `file.php: text/x-php; charset=us-ascii`. You can then use `iconv` to change files encoding.

Comment: `file -i wp-settings.php 
wp-settings.php: text/x-php; charset=us-ascii` 
local encoding is us-ascii, could it be a problem ? should I convert files to utf-8 or something else ?

Comment: I do not think encoding above is a problem, because, I just checked my other projects available locally, they too have same encoding, and they are working fine...

Comment: I think there is some problem with the files I copy from other places to my disk, because, I just installed wordpress from the scratch, and it worked without any problem... I am not sure what problem I might be having with my local config or settings... any suggestion  ???

Comment: The problem might be related to your customized plugin. What happens if you remove the files? (move them somewhere else)

Comment: ok, I removed the custom plug in, (the coming soon plugin), and it all working fine... but, very strange, why is the plugin working online...