# PHP - How can I detect ANSI text file?

Tags: php

I want to detect file encoding if it is ANSI or if it is UTF-8 and Unicode. I only find out how to Detect UTF-8

```
if (mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents($file), 'UTF-8', true))
{
    echo "UTF-8";
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "ANSI text". You'll have to check for a specific legacy charset. Or "ASCII" if that is what you meant.

Comment: And all you can really do is check if a file is not *valid* UTF-8. Other than that it's pretty much guesswork.

Comment: have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505562/detect-file-encoding-in-php

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

/* Specify encoding_list character encoding by comma separated list */

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($str, "ASCII, UTF-8, UNICODE");
```

it will print the detected encoding with respect to list

Comment: @ImBigNoob There's no such thing as a 'Unicode' encoding.